# can not get proper output when i write in .csv file...the comma separated text is being written in multiple columns,i want only two columns

Tags: python, csv, file-handling

```
def classify(self):        
    for i in self.tweets:
        tw = self.tweets[i]
        count = 0
        res = {}
        for t in tw:
            label = self.classifier.classify(self.helper.extract_features(t.split()))
            if(label == 'positive'):
                self.pos_count[i] += 1
            elif(label == 'negative'):                
                self.neg_count[i] += 1
            elif(label == 'neutral'):                
                self.neut_count[i] += 1
            result = {'text': t, 'tweet': self.origTweets[i][count], 'label': label}
            res[count] = result
            count += 1
        #end inner loop
        self.results[i] = res
```

[image: this is the screenshot of my csv file]

```
 def writeOutput(self,filename, writeOption='wb'):
    fp = open(filename, writeOption)
    if(fp):
        for i in self.results:
            res = self.results[i]
            for j in res:[enter image description here][1]
                item = res[j]
                text = item['text'].strip()
                label = item['label']
                writeStr = label+" , "+text+"\n"
                pickle.dump(writeStr,fp)
```

I am writing 'label' and 'text' in csv "filename", but the text is getting divided in multiple columns which causing further error in my work.

Comment: I have to ask: Where in the world did you get the idea to use `pickle.dump` to write a csv file?

Comment: Are you sure the `text ` variable doesn't have any commas in it ? I usually use `text.replace(",", " ")` to make sure there aren't any when writing csv.

Comment: Why don't you use the actual [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module?

Comment: @roganjosh can you please elaborate with my code? thank you!

Comment: @Aran-Fey please elaborate !thank you!

Comment: What does `self.results` look like? Please add a few rows to your question (in text format)

Comment: @MartinEvans i have added rows for 'self.results'

Comment: I meant, copy the output of `print(self.results[:4])` so we can see the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Python's CSV library. This takes a list of values and writes it to a file, automatically adding suitable delimiters and quoting to make it a proper comma separated file. In your case, your text contains commas, as such these items will automatically have `"` correctly added around them. This can be done roughly as follows:

```
import csv


def writeOutput(self, filename, writeOption='wb'):
    with open(filename, writeOption) as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

        for i in self.results:
            res = self.results[i]
            for j in res:
                item = res[j]
                csv_output.writerow([item['label'], item['text'].strip()])
```